# iBatis.NET to insert record with Oracle stored procedure, return record ID

Tags: oracle, ibatis, ibatis.net, mybatis

I am attempting to insert a record in an Oracle table with a Function, which would be called through iBatis.NET. Function works as expected in Oracle when called directly.

I have tried using `<statement>` and `<insert>` SqlMap but I can't get iBatis.NET to call the function, and Oracle doesn't support returning anything from Stored Procedure.

I would need to pass properties of my object as parameters to a function/sproc and get back the ID of this new record.

What would be a good combination of iBatis.NET call / SQLMap / Sproc or Function signature in Oracle?

The documentation only has examples of in-line SQL and I can only use sprocs.

Due to the number of properties in real objects, the hash-map and number of parameters is in the 30+.

Ideally I would be able to do this (doesn't work):

`<procedure id="InsertPerson" parameterClass="BOM.Person">
    TestDB.PERSON_PKG.InsertPerson(#Name#, #Age#)
</procedure>`

Domain object:

```
public class Person
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    decimal Age { get; set; }
}
```

iBatis.NET call:

```
int personID = mapper.Insert("InsertPerson", person);
```

Oracle Stored Procedure:

```
   FUNCTION InsertPerson(
             p_Name IN Persons.Name%TYPE,
             p_Age IN Persons.Age%TYPE,
             ) RETURN NUMBER
   IS
             NEW_ID Persons.ID%TYPE;
   BEGIN
            SELECT Persons_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO NEW_ID FROM DUAL; /* Get new ID*/

            INSERT INTO Persons(ID, Name, Age)
            SELECT NEW_ID, p_Name, p_Age from dual; /* Insert record */
            COMMIT;

            RETURN NEW_ID;
   END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps someone else, I was unable to find a workaround to my problem.

I ended up implementing this as a Stored Procedure which takes input parameters for all fields to be inserted in to a table, and one output parameter which returns the unique ID generated by sequence.

After executing `mapper.Insert(...)` I simply read the output parameter and return it.

C#:

```
mapper.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable);

// Add new Record
Hashtable param = new Hashtable();
param.Add("ID", user.ID); // Output
param.Add("DeptID", user.DeptID);
param.Add("RightID", user.RightID);

mapper.Insert("AddUserRight", param);

user.ID = Convert.ToInt32(param["ID"]);
```

MyBATIS map:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<sqlMap namespace="CCP" xmlns="http://ibatis.apache.org/mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <statements>
        <procedure id="AddUserRight" parameterMap="AddUserRight-param">
            Database.USER_PKG.ADDUSERRIGHT
        </procedure>
    </statements>

    <parameterMaps>
        <parameterMap id="AddUserRight-param">
            <parameter property="ID" column="ID" direction="Output" />
            <parameter property="DeptID" column="DeptID" direction="Input" />
            <parameter property="RightID" column="RightID" direction="Input" />
        </parameterMap>
    </parameterMaps>
</sqlMap>
```

Sproc (Oracle):

```
   PROCEDURE AddUserRight(
            ID OUT USERRIGHTS.USERID%TYPE,
            DEPTID IN USERRIGHTS.DEPTID%TYPE,
            RIGHTID IN USERRIGHTS.RIGHTID%TYPE)
   IS
   BEGIN
        SELECT USERRIGHTS_UNQ_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO ID FROM DUAL;

             INSERT INTO USERRIGHTS(ID, DEPTID, RIGHTID)
             VALUES (ID, DEPTID, RIGHTID);
   END;
```